# Calculate the value of the integral.

Tags: calculus

See the attached image for the question.[image]

My intuition tells me to use the fundamental theorem of calculus to begin this problem. So I will have F(1) - F(0) = 9.

For part A, since the value of f(t) is changed to f(4t), this means that I need to adjust my bounds by dividing by 4 so thats how we get 0 to .25. Therefore, my answer for part A should be 9/4 correct?

However, I am confused about how to do parts b and c. I am helping a friend with the problem but I haven't done calculus for about 2 years, so if someone can point me in the right direction, I'll likely be able to solve the problem.

Comment: You're on the right track, but its not exactly correct. Please look at my answer for clarification.

Comment: You should just use substitution for each part (a,b and c). Do it formally (as shown by Varun) to avoid mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For parts (b) and (c), consider this.

Let us make the substitution $u = 1 - 4t$

We then have that $du = -4dt$

We also have to change our bounds. When $t = 0$, $u = 1$. When $t = 0.25$, $u = 0$.

We now have that our integral is:

$$\int_{1}^{0} \frac{f(u)}{-4}du$$

Rearranging, we have that:

$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1} f(u)du$$

According to the problem we have that:

$$\int_{0}^{1} f(u)du = 9$$

Instead of the variable $t$ we are using the variable $u$.

Now we substitute this is to get our final answer:

$$\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{1} f(u)du = \frac{1}{4}*9 = \frac{9}{4}$$

Hope this helped. The same process can be applied for part (c).

Comment if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I do recall how to do this process now.

Comment: @mmm No Problem. Math SE will help you find answer ;).